# How to resolve java.io.FilePermission error?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I am developing a java game for my school project from a tutorial which uses eclipse as its IDE. I am supposed to make this game in Netbeans but the problem is that after porting it gives an error like this.

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "E:\java game\TheBigGame\Unit 3 Day 7\build\data\character.png" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:555)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.<init>(URLImageSource.java:55)
at sun.applet.AppletImageRef.reconstitute(AppletImageRef.java:51)
at sun.misc.Ref.get(Ref.java:64)
at sun.applet.AppletViewer.getCachedImage(AppletViewer.java:395)
at sun.applet.AppletViewer.getImage(AppletViewer.java:390)
at java.applet.Applet.getImage(Applet.java:274)
at java.applet.Applet.getImage(Applet.java:296)
at kiloboltgame.StartingClass$1.run(StartingClass.java:66)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at kiloboltgame.StartingClass.init(StartingClass.java:64)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:434)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The game works well in Eclipse but is having troubles in Netbeans.
I saw a similar question and tried using policy tool, editing java.properties and java.policy in lib\security but still no progress. By the way I use Windows 8.1 (if that helps).
The game is made on an applet.

Answer (score -1):

I think your file is open. When under Windows, if a file is being used, sometimes you cannot open it from somewhere else..
Or it could be that you really don't have permissions :) right click on the file and check permissions (need to have all of them, read, write)

Comment: The file is not open. Also I am trying to open a text file in windows. I have written that I can open the file in eclipse.